# What is the correct order for using the conjunctions or and and

Tags: conjunctions

In a job posting one of the mandatory requirements is:

A degree from a recognized University **and** experience in financial management **or** an accounting designation.

Does this mean: (A degree and experience) or (a designation)
**or**              (A degree and experience) or (a degree and a designation)

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think that it's intrinsically ambiguous, and **remains** ambiguous even when you add in some knowledge of the context.

An "accounting designation" is an accounting **qualification** - it means they can call themselves a "chartered accountant" or something similar.  This status needs to be earned, and awarded, like a degree, but only after a certain amount of real-world achievement.

So, it could mean

A) a degree and ("some experience" or "a designation")

But, it could equally mean

B) (a degree and some experience) or "a designation".

In other words, *"we're interested in people who've gone to college then worked as an accountant, and we're **also** interested in people who **didn't** go to college but have experience of working as an accountant and have been awarded an accounting designation as a result of the accounting work they have done"*.  Both of those groups of people could be desirable candidates.

If the "designation" can only be achieved through working as an accountant (which is certainly the case with "chartered" status for example), then the phrase "experience plus a designation" is redundant, as it's impossible to get the designation *without* having had a substantial amount of experience.  This actually pushes the interpretation back towards meaning A):  (a degree and experience) or (a designation).

In order to be more sure, we'd need some more information about what the "designations" refer to.

Answer (score 1):

> Reference: http://www.investorwords.com/16891/accounting_designation.html

As you can see the link above, accounting designation means:

A type of professional credential that will prove the holder has achieved a high level of understanding, knowledge, and/or skills in their specific given profession. Accounting designations include Certified Public Accountant, or CPA.

Examples:

“ Be sure to include an accounting designation in the advertisement for our position at our new branch office that opens next month. ”

“ The accounting designation proved a few things about the person and we were really interested about it and how he managed to do it. ”

Considering these examples, your given sentence means: for that job you can provide either one these requirements:

1- A degree from a recognized University and experience in financial management.

2- An accounting designation.

Hope it helps